# Remove the Commits in Stored Procedure in Maria DB,What will be the impact if i remove all the commits?

Tags: mariadb

Stored procedure in Maria DB is having multiple commit statements,i have to remove the commit statements,so that the procedure performance will be increased,since the Maria DB is Auto-Commit by default,can i remove all the commit statements in the Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 1):

If `autocommit` is always on, then `COMMIT` does nothing.  Hence, removing them will have no impact.

But...  There may be cases where you need to group statements together between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.

If you are having trouble with performance, let's see some specifics; there may be much better parts of the code to look at.